# not able to convert "£12" nsstring to ascii format

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert nsstring (password) to MD5 and base64. For Ascii chars all are working fine but when I am trying to test for '£' or '?' sign, MD5 is giving me some junk values. Which is failing at my server end.

```
NSData *pwdData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(pwdData.bytes, pwdData.len, result);

[Base64 initialize];
[Base64 encode:result length:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

But same thing works fine in Android.

```
   MessageDigest msgDigest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("​MD5");

    msgDigest.update(s.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    byte bytes[] = msgDigest.digest();    

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes,​ Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

I am not sure is it problem with MD5 or BASE64? When Android is doing same and it works fine.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but I'd interpret `s.getBytes("US-ASCII")` to mean _"convert to 7/8-bit ASCII"_. And then you're updating the digest with `s.getBytes()` a second time? I guess this time it'll be in Java's UTF-16 (LE or BE?) encoding? So IMHO the Android code doesn't make much sense. Also note that the pound sign is not part of ASCII.

Comment: At least the iOS and Android code don't calculate the MD5 over the same byte array, that's for sure!

Comment: Why you think that CC_MD5 gives you junk values?

Comment: I am getting junk because server is not able to recognize char and throwing password validation error.

Comment: Sorry, which byte encoding do you want your string in? ASCII or UTF-16?

Comment: Tommy,I tried both encoding UTF16 and Ascii but server is not validating.

Comment: Maybe you want UTF-8 instead? But as long as you don't know what the server _really_ wants you'll be guessing. So I suggest you check that first, then decide which implementation is wrong and ask a new question on how to get exactly the required output on the platform that was wrong.

Comment: DarkDust, I just verified with Android and it takes as ASCII which is validating from server. See code msgDigest.update(s.getBytes("US-ASCII")); from android.

Comment: Then you need to output the bytes that Java's `getBytes("US-ASCII")` produces. The pound sign is not part of ASCII, so it either drops it or converts it into a different character like a `?`. You need to find out what it's doing. Once you know that we can discuss how to do that on iOS.

Comment: Also, be aware that if Java drops or converts the character, and the server does as well, that would mean that any password with special characters would be in danger! You almost certainly want to use UTF-8 instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can't encode a symbol like '£' to ASCII using lossy encoding. That gives the conversion process to drop special characters.

(The ASCII character set does not include the '£' symbol. It includes the US "#" symbol instead. back in the day, UK machines displayed that ASCII code as '£' and US machines used "#", but with the advent of Unicode, there are separate characters for both.

You should use UTF8, which, as I understand it,  is an encoding that outputs all ASCII characters, with ASCII tags that mark non-ASCII unicode characters in a way that they can be "reconstituted" when converted back to unicode.

(disclaimer: I'm not an expert on the different encodings of Unicode.)

Comment: I used UTF8 and UTF32 but still it shows me error. Not sure how android is working...

Comment: allowLossyConversion:NO

Comment: I tried allowLossyConversion:NO but it wont help me